# How can I start MySQL55 server into a java application

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class Clasa {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            String comand = "net start MySQL55";
            Process pr = rt.exec(" cmd.exe /C " + "net start MySQL55");

            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line = null;

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I try this and gives me the next error code: `Exited with error code 2`

Comment: Are you sure that `net start MySQL55` is correct command/name of service? Did you tested in in simple console?

Comment: Yes I test it and it works

Comment: Are you sure that this service is off when you run this code? Wrong name or already running service is for now only reason when I get this error code.

Comment: First of all I shutdown my sql server and after this I try this code and gives me error code 2. To work you must open with administrator rights the console.

Comment: There is a space character before CMD.EXE - it might be causing an issue. Error code 2 is file not found.

Comment: Try executing this code http://pastebin.com/Gug8vTeS. It will redirect all streams (including error stream) of process executing your command to our console. You can also print manually data from `pr.getErrorStream()`. Update your question with error message you got from error stream.

Comment: it give me the next error: System error 5 has occurred.

Access is denied.

Exited with error code 2

Comment: I think it is about the admin rights.